# Express route and save Mongoose document from request data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

This code uses npm "[Wagner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wagner-core)" and tring to update user's shopping cart

I don't understand why **req.user** can save like a mongoose document

What's the normal way to turn a request data to a document and save it
without using "Wagner"

---

The code below looks like this

Server get the data from request : **cart = req.body.data.cart**

and then update the cart : **req.user.data.cart = cart**

and now save the user data:  **req.user.save(....)**

My Question is why don't we need to create a Mongoose document first?

Isn't **req.user** just a JSON Object?

Thanks

```js
   passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
        User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
            done(err, user);
        });
    });
```

```js
   api.put('/me/cart', wagner.invoke(function(User) {
        return function(req, res) {
            var cart;
            try {
                cart = req.body.data.cart;
            } catch (e) {
                return res.
                status(status.BAD_REQUEST).
                json({ error: 'No cart specified!' });
            }
            req.user.data.cart = cart;
            req.user.save(function(error, user) {
                if (error) {
                    return res.
                    status(status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).
                    json({ error: error.toString() });
                }
                return res.json({ user: user });
            });
        };
    }));
```

User model is definde in another file 
and register by **wagner.factory**

```js
 var User =mongoose.model('User', require('./user'), 'users');
```

Comment: I don't have much idea about  this "Wagner" module. But i think first you have to create mongoose object for the user model using new key word. var      user = new User(req.user) then you can save the collection.

Comment: @Mariya JamesCan 
I just pass in  `req.user` into the `new User( )` directly ?
No need to set up each field by myself?  
Thanks

Comment: No required. If you the fields with the same name of the schema then it will work. But if it different you have to assign them seperately

Comment: @MariyaJames Thanks,I looked up some other code and documents and now seem to realize that why `req.user.save( )` is reasonable. Because `reaq.user` is set through `passport.deserializeUser`, it find a document from DB and set to req.user. So `req.user` is a document and can be saved. What do you think about it ?

Comment: Then it will work. But it will update your user collection. I am sorry i didn't went through your correct requirement. I was thinking about  creating new collection.